# Finding tangents and curvature of a parametric curve in 3D

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, homework, differential-geometry

I am in a calculus 3 class and cannot figure out how to get Mathematica to solve for unit tangent, normal tangent, binormal tangent, and curvature  without getting a supper messy result. This is the vector below:

$\qquad r(t)= (e^t \sin(2 t),\, e^t \cos(2t),\, 2e^t)$

Any help would be great. I know the formulas, but it is so messy that I feel that I am doing it wrong. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you seen `FrenetSerretSystem[]`?

Comment: Please post your code attempt, it’ll he easier to see where you’re going wrong.